# how to turn off console.log and warnings from webpack

Tags: npm, webpack

I am working on a play scala project that uses webpack and react. I did copy my webpack.config.js used for development and renamed it to webpack.prod.config.js. Using this new file, I want to be able to turn off the console.log and warnings. I used:

```
  plugins: [
      new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"),
      new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(/debug/, process.cwd() + './emptyDebug.js')    
    ],
   performance: {
       hints: false
   }
```

but I can still see those messages. Any solutions?

Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set the [`stats`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/#src/components/Sidebar/Sidebar.jsx) option to `'none'`:

```
stats: 'none'
```

Or you could use [webpack-dev-middleware](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware) and set [noInfo](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-noinfo-) to `true`. If you're using webpack-dev-server you can set [`noInfo`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-noinfo-) to `true` in the config:

```
devServer: {
  noInfo: true
}
```